# Cannot update the app state from custom component using React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I have the following `Codesandbox.io`:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qxkq5vvm1q

which is a basic `ReactJS / Redux` application.

The key components here are:

- a `Select` which gets its values something like through this way: `Redux (state manager) -> PanelMaterialSize (container) -> Select`
- one `Updater` component which takes care of update the values available on the `Select` through `Redux`
- `Alert` button, which when clicked should alert the value stored on the `store`

What should happen is:

1. when the user changes an option on the `Select`, that value should be stored on the store. This is actually happening properly - **OK**
2. if the `Select` gets its values changed (for example because the `Updater` component), then it should automatically change the value stored on the store with the value it is showing (something similar as if the user changes the value on it). Unfortunately this is not happening - **The Goal**

Here are some of the codes:

**./src/controls/Select/Select.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Select.scss";

class Select extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let { name, data, className, ...controlProps } = this.props;
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
    this.controlProps = controlProps;
    this.state = {
      [name]: data,
      className
    };
  }

  render() {
    let data = this.state[this.name];
    return (
      <div className="control-select" {...this.controlProps}>
        <div className="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--grey">
          <select className="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--grey">
            {this.props.data.length > 0 &&
              this.props.data.map((elem, index) => {
                return (
                  <option value={elem.value} key={index}>
                    {elem.text}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;
```

**src/controls/PanelMaterialSize/PanelMaterialSize.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./PanelMaterialSize.scss";
import Select from "../Select/Select";
import { setThemeList, setSelectedTheme } from "../../store/AppConfig/actions";

class PanelMaterialSize extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: "",
      options: []
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
        let target = e.target;
    let value = target.value;
        this.props.setSelectedTheme(value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="partial-designer-panel-material-size">
        <div>
          <div className="label-input">
            <div className="label">THEME</div>
            <div className="input">
              <Select
              name="selection"
              value={this.state.selection}
              data={this.props.themeList}
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
             />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = appState => {
  return {
    themeList: appState.appConfig.themeList,
    selectedTheme: appState.appConfig.selectedTheme,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setThemeList: themeList => dispatch(setThemeList(themeList)),
    setSelectedTheme: selectedTheme => dispatch(setSelectedTheme(selectedTheme)),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PanelMaterialSize);
```

Any idea on how to make the point 2 work?

If possible, please, provide back your solution on a forked `Codesandbox.io`.

Thanks!

Comment: https://oowv4o6jo5.codesandbox.io/ <<= Is this the you want?

Comment: thanks, I like this way (`reducer.js`) better than dispatching the action inside the `Updater`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Updater` component is producing new list of themes every 3seconds

It must also dispatch `setSelectedTheme` action to update selected theme in application state